# Did Somnath Temple ever have a direct gateway to heaven?

Tags: shiva, jyotirlinga

Did Somnath Temple have a direct gateway to heaven. I heard about this story in TV Serial Devon ke dev Mahadev. I want to know about the story and whether it is a written story or a folklore.