# Which scriptures contain the story of Sudama?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana, reference-request, harivamsa

This story is so quintessentially tied up with Krishna Bhagavatam - but Bard says

> The story of Sudama is found in several Hindu scriptures, including:

> The Bhagavata Purana, which is one of the most important Puranas in Hinduism.

> The Mahabharata, which is an epic poem that tells the story of the Pandava and Kaurava princes.

> The Harivamsa, which is a supplement to the Mahabharata.

> The Narada Purana, which is a collection of stories about the sage Narada.

Is this correct?

Comment: BardAI's authenticity is no more than that of Wikipedia. We at the website are not here to authenticate every single word of either.

Comment: This is just the motivation/background of the question.  Many questions are asked this way, for example, https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7849/did-somnath-temple-ever-have-a-direct-gateway-to-heaven